# Aluminum corner bead mud adhesion

Tags: drywall, primer

I've noticed on a couple of small repair interventions, aluminum drywall corner L-bead does not hold mud as adhesively as drywall does, due to the texture/grip of aluminum. Is there a way to improve it by some kind of primer?

It's usually not a problem when the application mass is large so the less adhesive part around the bead is cohesive with a bigger one on drywall. But, when it doesn't have much drywall to piggyback on, it easily peels off or doesn't stay when applied.

Comment: Can you include a picture of the one you use? There are embedded corners, taped corners, and covers etc...

Comment: @P2000 I don't have a picture. Just L shape I think 1-1/4 each side